# How to resume XMPP groupchat window in Irssi (using bitlbee)?

Tags: chat, irssi, xmpp

I use [Bitlbee](http://www.bitlbee.org/) to chat in XMPP-networks within my IRC-client [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/). This works great so far, and recently I started using XMPP Multi User Chats as an alternative to IRC-channels.

I set up a channel using `chat add <account> <room@xmppserver.net>` in the &bitlbee control window, set `chan <room> set autojoin true` and entered `/join #room` in the &bitlbee window to join that groupchat. It then appears as a unique Irssi window in the status bar. This seems to work ok too, but with one exception:

Since I idle in the channels 24/7 my irssi has to cope with the every-night-24h-DSL-disconnection by the ISP. After it automatically reconnects, it does kind of rejoin that XMPP-groupchat, but the traffic of the groupchat does not go back to the unique irssi window, but keeps flooding &bitlbee with messages from `root` telling me about a `Groupchat Message from unknown JID <jid>: <message>` - which is the traffic of the groupchat. The unique groupchat window is gone after the reconnect, and I will again have to go `/join #room` in &bitlbee to get it back.

Even worse, the window number is unused before I rejoin the groupchat, and if I get a query from any network, the window nests in that unused window spot, so I will first have to remove that query from the spot, and then move the rejoined groupchat to that window number.

I want my groupchat window to resume after the reconnect just like every other IRC channel too. How can I get this done? Any ideas?

/edit: now i set `chan <room> set autojoin false` but it did not change anything. so could that be a bug in bitlbee, that ignores that autojoin true setting?

Comment: on disconnect it says `mcnesium was kicked from #room by root [Chatroom closed by server]` in the unique window, which I can see in the history at manual resuming the window.